# limit cycle in high dimension system (8 dimension for example)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, physics, stability-theory

I am very new to the nonlinear dynamical-systems. I wonder if there is a method to determine when a limit cycle situation will occur in the non-linear dynamical system, which is described by the differential equations:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x}=f(\mathbf{x}),
$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_8)^T$, the nonlinear term is just $Vx_{2}x_j$ for $dx_j/dt=f_j(x) (j=5,6,7,8)$.

As far as I know, before analyzing the stability of the system, we need to know the fixed point $x^*$, which satisfied $f(x^*)=0$. But here the solution $x^*$ is hard to obtain, or I can only obtain numerical solution through numerical method, such as RK4. In the numerical calculation, there will be limit cycle situation (sometimes just stable, determineing by my parameters), which means I can not get the fixed point $x^*$ from the Rk4.

$\mathbf{Question}$: I want to know if there is method to judge when the limit cycle occure, in the case where I cannot know the fixed point $x^*$ under certain parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: It is unlikely that you get a closed trajectory in dimensions larger than $2$. The best you can get is that the trajectory remains bounded. Even if in dimension 4 you have two separate 2-dimensional systems with a limit cycle each it is unlikely that they have a common period (which best would be a small multiple of the elementary period of each).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, the differential equations mentioned above are getted from an single three level atom-light physics system. It is indeed possible that the numerical result I obtained is just a bounded trajectory. But how can I judge the bounded trajectory is result from limit cycle, or just optimize trajectory from Rk4 is periodic. [Ref](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.131.143002)

Comment: You can not prove such qualitative claims with numerical methods. Now if the theory reduces the effective state dimension, that every solution converges towards some2-dimensional manifold, you can use the 2D theorems to prove the existence of limit cycles. But now you also have to consider topology, such a sub-manifold will seldom be flat.